# How to save the set of dominated solutions while solving NSGA 2 in pymoo into a dataframe?

Tags: python, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I am trying to solve a multiobjective optimization problem with 3 objectives and 2 decision variables using NSGA 2. The pymoo code for NSGA2 algorithm and termination criteria is given below. My pop_size is 100 and n_offspring is 100. The algorithm is iterated over 100 generations. I want to store all 100 values of decision variables considered in each generation for all 100 generations in a dataframe.

NSGA2 implementation in pymoo code:

```
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation

algorithm = NSGA2(
    pop_size=20,
    n_offsprings=10,
    sampling=get_sampling("real_random"),
    crossover=get_crossover("real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15),
    mutation=get_mutation("real_pm", prob=0.01,eta=20),
    eliminate_duplicates=True
)
from pymoo.factory import get_termination

termination = get_termination("n_gen", 100)

from pymoo.optimize import minimize

res = minimize(MyProblem(),
               algorithm,
               termination,
               seed=1,
               save_history=True,
               verbose=True)
```

What I have tried (My reference: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496005/how-to-obtain-the-objective-function-value-and-values-of-variables-during-each-i)):

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame (algorithm.pop)
df2.head(10)
```

The result from above code is blank and on passing

```
print(df2)
```

I get

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glad you intend to use pymoo for your research. You have correctly enabled the `save_history` option, which means you can access the algorithm objects.
To have all solutions from the run, you can combine the offsprings (`algorithm.off`) from each generation. Don't forget the `Population` objects contain `Individual` objectives. With the `get` method you can get the `X` and `F` or other values. See the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2 from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation, ZDT1 from pymoo.factory import get_termination from pymoo.model.population import Population from pymoo.optimize import minimize

problem = ZDT1()

algorithm = NSGA2(
    pop_size=20,
    n_offsprings=10,
    sampling=get_sampling("real_random"),
    crossover=get_crossover("real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15),
    mutation=get_mutation("real_pm", prob=0.01,eta=20),
    eliminate_duplicates=True )

termination = get_termination("n_gen", 10)


res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               termination,
               seed=1,
               save_history=True,
               verbose=True)

all_pop = Population()

for algorithm in res.history:
    all_pop = Population.merge(all_pop, algorithm.off)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_pop.get("X"), columns=[f"X{i+1}" for i in range(problem.n_var)])

print(df)
```

Another way would be to use a callback and fill the data frame each generation. Similar as shown here: https://pymoo.org/interface/callback.html

Comment: This gives me the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymoo.model'

Comment: please find the answer for the new version above.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for pymoo==0.6.0.1

```
import pandas as pd
from pymoo.termination import get_termination

from pymoo.core.population import Population
from pymoo.optimize import minimize

from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2

from pymoo.problems.multi import ZDT1

problem = ZDT1()

algorithm = NSGA2(
    pop_size=20,
    n_offsprings=10)


res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               termination=get_termination("n_gen", 10),
               seed=1,
               save_history=True,
               verbose=True)

all_pop = Population()

for algorithm in res.history:
    all_pop = Population.merge(all_pop, algorithm.off)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_pop.get("X"), columns=[f"X{i+1}" for i in range(problem.n_var)])

print(df)
```